# Backpropagatable Transformations with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to transform general tensors / vectors in Tensorflow, but to have a concrete example let's say rotate images.
For this I would like to have a rotation matrix R, which is learned by my network, i.e. there should be gradients computable.
How would you do this?

I found tf.contrib.image.transform, but for this it is said no gradients are computed into the transformation parameters.
Via py_func also the gradients are not available or would have to be calculated by hand - before writing a long custom solution for this (if even possible), are there maybe any ready-to-use solutions?

I cannot be the first one doing this.
For the requested code: I just want to feed an image as input, maybe apply some convolutional layer and in the end get a 2x2 matrix representing my transformation:

```
conv_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, 16, [3, 3], strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
...
M = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(conv_n, 4, activation_fn=tf.nn.tanh)
```

The matrix M then describes how my indices are transformed (imagining each pixel in the image as a vector with endpoint x, y), and I move each pixel then to its new location.
In numpy I could for example do this:

```
indices = []

for i in range(28):
    for j in range(28):
        indices.append([i, j])

indices = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(np.asarray(indices), 0), self.batch_size, 0)

transformed = []
for b in range(self.batch_size):
    transformed.append(tf.matmul(indices[b], M[b]))

transformed = tf.stack(transformed)

transformed_img = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 28, 28))
for b in range(self.batch_size):
    transformed_img[b, transformed[b, :, :, 0].astype(np.int32), transformed[b, :, :, 1].astype(np.int32)]  = input_img[b, :, :, 0]
```

Comment: You could use the general form of rotation matrix and keep the rotation angle as learnable variable. Please post some code so that we could have something to work with...

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I added some code - is that helping? note that I do not know beforehand whether it is a rotation and want to be able to express arbitrary transformations.